# Errors on Building a project that occur only on my machine (other developers don't have this issue)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, git, git-bash

I am working on an C#/MVC project in corporation with other developers. The project works just fine with everyone except my machine.

We are using **git** with the project.

Whenever I try to build the project, I get the below errors/warnings:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Reporting' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) MvcPortal   C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\MvcPortal\Controllers\TestingController.cs   18  Active
Error       CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Reporting' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) MvcPortal   C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\MvcPortal\Helpers\ReportUtils.cs 6   Active
Error       CS0246  The type or namespace name 'LocalReport' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   MvcPortal   C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\MvcPortal\Helpers\ReportUtils.cs 84  Active
Error       CS0246  The type or namespace name 'LocalReport' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   MvcPortal   C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\MvcPortal\Helpers\ReportUtils.cs 96  Active
Error       CS0246  The type or namespace name 'LocalReport' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   MvcPortal   C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\MvcPortal\Helpers\ReportUtils.cs 124 Active
Warning     CS0108  'SupplierLController.View()' hides inherited member 'Controller.View()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.    MvcPortal   C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\MvcPortal\Controllers\SupplierLiaisonController.cs   60  Active
Warning             The referenced component 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms' could not be found.  MvcPortal           
Warning             Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.  MvcPortal
```

When I Googled these errors, I found some solutions, but if I perform any of these solutions, they will get pushed into the repository and then pulled by other developers! This might cause further problems because my machine is the only one that has these errors?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Seems like the assembly Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms is missing from your computer.

Comment: @rory.ap thank you! I think you are right. Any advice how to fix this?

Comment: install the redistributable.

Comment: i think you need to install your nuget references (maybe). depending on der vs version / project type the exact procedure can vary -  if you ask the other devs how they did it - they should be able to give you an exact instruction, because they have done it.

Comment: And while you are at it, write a manual with all such steps for the next dev that might join you say next year...

Comment: The issue is with `using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;` For some reasons, the code is not able to locate the **Reporting** class. Could this be a security related issue?